# Ubuntu 18.04 is consuming battery like crazy

Tags: power-management, battery

I bought a new laptop, a Legion 545. And I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.

The laptop battery time is almost 60 minutes. I have tried to optimize it with powertop and tlp, but the battery discharge rate remains>38 any lead. I may have to go back to Windows - which I don't want to...

> The battery reports a discharge rate of 39.5 W
>   The power consumed was 0.00 J
>   System baseline power is estimated at 40.5 W

Comment: My laptop battery time, using Ubuntu 19.10, is about five hours -- about the same as Windows. Use the Search box at the top of the page to look for similar questions - and their solutions. Usually, rapid discharging is due to some specific hardware that you have, like a Video card or GPU, that was poorly supported when 18.04 was built. You can try a newer release of Ubuntu to see if your hardware manufacturer improved their support.

Comment: Also, Ubuntu 'flavours' are listed at http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: @user535733 just have followed a lot of suggestions. most of the guys are saying to run **TLP** or **powertop** I have tried both . but even though battery consumption not reduced than 40 W  which is crazy. I am trying 19. let's see if it works, really don't want to move back on windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably caused by your GPU, your OS is probably using your Nvidia card to do all the work.

I suggest you update to the latest drivers for your cards, as well as using Nvidia's proprietary driver if you have no problem with that.

Probably the easiest way you can go about fixing that is to try the `prime indicator` extension for GNOME, and set the default card to your Intel card. You might also wanna install `dim on battery power` for a little more kick.

P.S., check for your battery health as well. You can check for this by comparing energy levels, what you get and what your battery is designed to give you.